# Storing filestream to disk using PHP, MSSQL and FreeTDS

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I have an MSSQL database that has files stored as blobs, the file sizes vary. I'd developed a proof of concept and used the SQLSRV driver for PHP, the code worked well. My client required the application to run in a Linux environment so I've moved to FreeTDS, the only problem that I seem to have is that the `mssql_fetch_array` function I'm using isn't retrieving the entire blob. I came to this conclusion when I noticed the files being stored on disk were all 63KB, I changed code to `var_dump` the variable that held the binary data, it showed `["attachment"]=> string(64512)` irrespective of the size of the blob (3,9mb in the DB).

When I used the SQLSRV driver, I had to specify the data being retrieved was binary and I didn't have these issues, however, this is consistently failing. An excerpt from my code is below, please point out where my approach is wrong.

```
    $stmt3 = mssql_query($tsql3) or 
            die("<p style='color:red;'>{addFile} Could not $query: " . mssql_get_last_message() . "</p>");;

        // handle the notices with attachments, add meta and save binary info to filesystem
        while ( $noticeAttachmentList = mssql_fetch_array( $stmt3) ){

            $c = $noticeAttachmentList[1]; // filename
            $header = $noticeAttachmentList[2]; // file header
            $download = $noticeAttachmentList[3]; // binary data
            $nID = $noticeAttachmentList[4]; // FK for external system      

            // create the filename path & make the filename web-friendly
            $filename = $uploadsDir;
            $filename .= str_replace(' ', '_',$c);

            // create entry in notice_attachement table
            $noticeFileInfo = array(
                'fk_notice_id'      => $noticeID, 
                'filename'          => $c, 
                'post_id'           => $postID, 
                'notice_attachment_id'          => $nID, 
                'date_added'                => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())

                );

            // check if the file exists
            if (file_exists($filename)){
                echo "<p class='error'>Error: The file ".$filename." exists already in the destination folder.</p>";
                return false;
            }  
            // create the file
            if (!file_exists($filename)){
                echo "Your file, ". $filename ."is ready for download<br/>";
                // download the file from the database and store in uploadsDir
                file_put_contents($filename, $download);
                //var_dump($download);
                return true;
            }

            $file = $metaAttachmentPath . str_replace(' ', '_',$c);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several places where this limitation can come into play, but I'm guessing it is probably in your FreeTDS configuration (typically in `/etc/freetds.conf` or `/etc/freetds/freetds.conf`).

Look for a line similar to this:

```
text size = 64512
```

And change it to something like this in the `[global]` section:

```
test size = 4294967295
```

That should fix it right up - I believe the default setting in `freetds.conf` is a legacy `[global]` settings from Sybase.